# Use a Cell Value to Control a Table's Filter function (not pivot table)

Tags: excel, filter

I would like to be able to use the 'drop down lists' to control the function of the filters on the table to the right.

Example: If I put into the 'drop down lists' for Money: to = 10, my table will filter down to 1 - Sharon - 10, and 2 - Jean - 10. (The same as if you went over to the money filter carrot on the table and only selected 10).  Then if I add into the 'drop down lists' for Name: to = Sharon, my list would filter down to only 1 - Sharon - 10.

I am not interested in pivot tables or slicers for this issue as I would like it to be easily mimickable in Google Sheets.

Thank you again for looking!

[image: This is my simple sheet]

Comment: You may be looking for [slicers](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-slicers-to-filter-data-249f966b-a9d5-4b0f-b31a-12651785d29d)

Comment: Definitely doable with VBA.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not looking for slicers, but yes, basically getting my cell to function like a slicer.

Comment: Is it possible without VBA, but perhaps Javascript?

Comment: What's the reasoning behind the very limited options? pivots, slicers, and lastly vba all seem like good options

Comment: Maybe possible with Office-JS but I don't see why you would go that route tbh.

Comment: I'm hoping to use the input in the cells in other locations in my sheet, so although using the slicer does solve the issue of adjusting the table it does it in a way not in the fashion I'm looking for... In the same way, that I could just use the filter carrot on the table if my only requirement was the table visual output.  As for the VBA, if/when I can come up with a solution to my issue here, I'll be able to convert it to an online google doc, which doesn't allow me to use VBA.  These restraints are certainly what is giving me issues.